# How to make a Field injected multiple times to the Form unique in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form2, zend-form-collection, zend-form-fieldset

I have a pretty complex form with several nested `Fieldset`s and `Collection`s. Some parts of the form are constant, other parts are variable:

BasicSettings
    EndpointBasicSource (constant part)
    EndpointBasicTarget (constant part)
SpecificSettings
    EndpointType{TYPE}Source (variable part)
    EndpointType{TYPE}Target (variable part)

The `EndpointBasicSource` and `EndpointBasicTarget` contain a `ServerFieldset`, that provides the `Field` `server_name`. That means: The form contains at least `2` `server_name` `Field`s.

In the `SpecificSettings` depending on the `EndpintType` no, one, or both sides can contain a servers `Collection` (`options.target_element.type => ServerFieldset`) with up to `5` servers in it.

Here is a strongly simplified schema:

[image]

Now the servers should get unique (in all the `server_name` fields in the form a value may not recur). But how to do this? The problem is, that the `ServerFieldset` is injected via multiple other `Fieldset`s/`Collection`s and the uniqueness validation needs to relate to the `server_name` `Field`s in all of them.

**How can this problem be solved and a uniqueness validation for all the `server_name` in the entire form implemented?**

Comment: Have you tried using a [Callback validator](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.validator.callback.html)? There you can get a specific input $value and the $context, which is an array with all the other inputs.